# Adding Users to Asterisk pbx

Tags: ios

I wanted to add users into Astrisk,i am able to add manually but i need to add programetically something like sending Http request or might be anything but my concern is that it should be through programetically(in objective c if possible because it's iOS app).
Please let me knowif you have any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could pull the data from an SQL server and inject them into the DB? Asterisk seems to support [SIP peers from MySQL](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+mysql+peers)

Comment: Ok.Thanks it might be helpfull

Comment: Actually i wanted to clerify that if you are inserting data into your conf or iax file then can you able to get update on that time,if yes,hw?